# JavaScript get child element

Tags: javascript, html

Why this does not work in firefox i try to select the category and then make subcategory visible.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_sub(cat) {
      var cat = document.getElementById("cat");
      var sub = cat.getElementsByName("sub");
      sub[0].style.display='inline'; 
}

</script>
```

-

```
<ul>
    <li id="cat" onclick="show_sub(this)">
        Top 1
        <ul style="display:none" name="sub">
            <li>Sub 1</li>
            <li>Sub 2</li>
            <li>Sub 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Top 2</li>
    <li>Top 3</li>
    <li>Top 4</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT Answer is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function show_sub(cat) {
      cat.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = (cat.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display == "none") ? "inline" : "none";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I would consider using a class `sub` instead of the name attribute, in this situation. If you want to use jQuery it is as simple as `$('#cat .sub').css('display', 'inline')`.

Comment: You ignore the `cat` parameter, why?

Comment: This is javascript question i dont need jquery. @gdoron what yo mean i ignore `cat`?

Comment: You override the value you get in `cat`. Anyway, when you say it doesn't work in FF, does it work with other browser?

Comment: You pass a variable into the function, and then don't use that variable. Which makes it a little redundant (unless you've just simplified the demo).

Comment: it does not work anywhere just give me working version please.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

ULs don't have a name attribute, but you can reference the ul by tag name.

Try replacing line 3 in your script with this:

```
var sub = cat.getElementsByTagName("UL");
```

Comment: Wor that worked gr8 all i needed was
`cat.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = (cat.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display == "none") ? "inline" : "none";`

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest doing something similar to:

```
function show_sub(cat) {
    if (!cat) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById(cat)) {
        var parent = document.getElementById(cat),
            sub = parent.getElementsByClassName('sub');
        if (sub[0].style.display == 'inline'){
            sub[0].style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            sub[0].style.display = 'inline';
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById('cat').onclick = function(){
    show_sub(this.id);
};​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XnazT/).

Though the above relies on the use of a `class` rather than a `name` attribute equal to `sub`.

As to why your original version "didn't work" (not, I must add, a particularly useful description of the problem), all I can suggest is that, in Chromium, the JavaScript console reported that:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getElementsByName'.

One approach to working around the older-IE family's limitations is to use a custom function to emulate `getElementsByClassName()`, albeit crudely:

```
function eBCN(elem,classN){
    if (!elem || !classN){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var children = elem.childNodes;
        for (var i=0,len=children.length;i<len;i++){
            if (children[i].nodeType == 1
                &&
                children[i].className == classN){
                    var sub = children[i];
            }
        }
        return sub;
    }
}

function show_sub(cat) {
    if (!cat) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById(cat)) {
        var parent = document.getElementById(cat),
            sub = eBCN(parent,'sub');
        if (sub.style.display == 'inline'){
            sub.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            sub.style.display = 'inline';
        }
    }
}

var D = document,
    listElems = D.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i=0,len=listElems.length;i<len;i++){
    listElems[i].onclick = function(){
        show_sub(this.id);
    };
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XnazT/5/).

Comment: Just to make it more clear: there is no `element.getElementsByName`, only [`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName).

Comment: Is there way to eliminate `getElementsByClassName` its not compatible with IE 6 and 7

Comment: Gr8, you just had typo var sub = children[i];
I also find out you need to put script after html not in head for it to work.

Comment: All I can say is that, [typo fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XnazT/5), it works for me on Firefox 12/Ubuntu 11.04. What version/OS are you using?

Comment: its fixed now i was putting it on top in head at first that's why it was not working.

Comment: Sorry had to take off the answer from you and give to someone else becase all i needed to do is change one line of my code to make it work i don't know why it has to be so complex as you in your second example described.
Answer is:
`cat.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = (cat.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display == "none") ? "inline" : "none";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function show_sub(cat) {
    var parent = cat,
    sub = parent.getElementsByClassName('sub');
    if (sub[0].style.display == 'inline'){
        sub[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        sub[0].style.display = 'inline';
    }
}

document.getElementById('cat').onclick = function(){
    show_sub(this);
};​
```

and use this for IE6 & 7

```
if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName!='function') {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function() {
        var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
        var ei = new Array();
        for (i=0;i<elms.length;i++) {
            if (elms[i].getAttribute('class')) {
               ecl = elms[i].getAttribute('class').split(' ');
                for (j=0;j<ecl.length;j++) {
                    if (ecl[j].toLowerCase() == arguments[0].toLowerCase()) {
                        ei.push(elms[i]);
                    }
                }
            } else if (elms[i].className) {
                ecl = elms[i].className.split(' ');
                for (j=0;j<ecl.length;j++) {
                    if (ecl[j].toLowerCase() == arguments[0].toLowerCase()) {
                        ei.push(elms[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ei;
    }
}
```