# How can I get a reference to a child element in an unordered list

Tags: javascript, html

I created a vertical menu using unordered list. Within the list, there are subitems that are not displayed until a click event. How do I get a reference to the first ul child element of an li element to change its display style from "none" to ""?

When I click on mnu03, how do I get a reference to mnu031. Right now I'm just adding a "1" to the parent id to create the id of the child, which is kludgy.

I don't want to use jQuery.

The markup follow:

```
<pre>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="mnu01" onclick="this">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="mnu02" onclick="this">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="mnu03" onclick="this">Item 3</a>
         <ul id="mnu031" style="display:none;" >
             <li><a href="#" id="mnuSub031" onclick="this">Item S1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" id="mnuSub032" onclick="this">Item S2</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" id="mnu04" onclick="this">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="mnu05" onclick="this">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
</pre>
```

Comment: Here is a similar question that I think addresses what you are looking to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567709/javascript-get-child-element

Comment: have you tried `nextSibling`?

Comment: `document.getElementById('mnu03').getElementsByTagName('UL')[0]`, if it's inside a handler for `#mnu03`, just use `this.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0]`

Comment: What browsers do you want to support?

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript code where you bind to the click:

```
this.parentElement.querySelector('ul').style.display = 'block';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CDXH5/

You have some mismatched quotes in your html, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

assign a class to your li element.

```
    window.onload=function() {
var obj=document.getElementsByClassName('x');
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
{

obj[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
 for(var i=0;i< this.childElementCount ;i++ )
    {
        // write ur code here  this.children[i] is your reference
    }

 });

}   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS sibling selectors for styling only the first of it's class. The following selects only the first ul under an li

```
 li > ul {}
```

There are other sibling type selectors that may you want to try out.

- The descendant selector
- The adjacent sibling combinator
- The general sibling combinator.

**The Descendant Selector:** 
This is styling any list items that are anywhere underneath an unordered list.

```
ul li{}
```

**Adjacent Sibling Combinator:**

```
p + p { font-size: smaller; } /* Selects all paragraphs that directly follow another paragraph */
```

**The child combinator selector:** Selecting  tags that are strictly direct children of `<p>` tags in your markup.

```
p > img
```

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but it's what I would use if it must be JS free.
[css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)