# How to only change the text in a DOM element without replacing any child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a simple html structure

```
<h1>Title text <span>inner text</span></h1>
```

What I want is to replace only the text (Title text) without disturb the `<span>` text. Is this possible?

I don't want to add any other dom element, I would like to keep that structure. I been doing this of course.

```
$("h1").text("new text");
```

But you can guess... will replace all the innert text and the `span` text element as well.

Possible solution:
I was thinking in copy in a variable the text of the span and then concatenate it with the new `<h1>` text, But I think maybe exist a better and clean way to do it.

Comment: i think your solution is good, you can also put each text in its own element to avoid this problem in the first place

Comment: Or you can use text nodes.

Comment: Can you wrap `Title text` with a span? E.g. `<span class='title'>Title text</span>`

Comment: @ibu i agree. imo i try not to use any html that comes with styling out of the box, ie: header tags <b> <i> etc. I try to do as much styling as possible in my stylesheet. But to reitereate what Ibu said, just wrap the span in a different header tag and that'll solve your problem. I'm assuming it's that you want it to be two blocks of text so they should be separate anyway.

Comment: @jrummell what I don't want to do is add a new element like <span class='title'>

Comment: Yeah I know I can add a extra markup but I was asking me if exist any easy way to access only to the text of the dom element, but I guess the text and the innerHTML is the same right? come in the same package :S

Comment: @nahum: `I guess the text and the innerHTML is the same right?`. No text and html values are not the same. In JavaScript the `.value` of the `h1` is `undefined` and the `innerHTML` is `Title text <span>inner text</span>`. In jQuery when using `.text()` you get `Title text inner text` while `.html()` will give you `Title text <span>inner text</span>`. When referring to text you get just the text without the HTML tags. When referring to html you get it all, text as well as tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [**jQuery.contents()**](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) you can replace the `nodeValue` similar to this:

```
$("h1").contents()[0].nodeValue = "new text ";
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kCnD8/) using `jQuery.contents()` to replace a text node

---

Answer (score 4):

```
$("h1").each(function() {
    var textNode = document.createTextNode("new text");
    this.replaceChild(textNode, this.firstChild);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FvbJa/

Answer (score 2):

Another short jQuery solution:

```
$("h1").contents().first().replaceWith("new text");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FvbJa/1/

Comment: I think this is better than contents()[0] because you are keeping the jquery object. you can keep chaining methods, but it's almost the same

Answer (score 2):

This is gonna work without jquery:

```
$title = documento.querySelector('your h1 element');
$title.firstChild.nodeValue = 'New Title text';
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567709/javascript-get-child-element) which might be useful.

you can get the child element by doing this:

```
var h1_elt = document.getElementById(h1_elt_id);
var span = h1_elt.getElementsByTagName("span");
```

You can then use the spans innerHTML as part of the h1 elements innerHTML, i.e.:
    h1_elt.innerHTML = "new text "+span.innerHTML+""

The only thing you would need to change about your HTML is to give the h1 element an id attribute, then use that in place of h1_elt_id.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work.

```
var h1 = document.getElementById("h1"),
    children = Array.prototype.slice.call(h1.children),
    newText = document.createTextNode("Hello. ");

h1.innerHTML = "";
h1.appendChild(newText);

while(children) {
    h1.appendChild(children.shift());
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TFYmv/

Basically what you're doing is taking a picture of all the children in a specific element, changing the element completely, then re-appending all the previous children back onto the parent element using the picture we took.

Answer (score -1):

```
const ChgBtn = document.querySelector('#change-title')
const title = document.querySelector('#page-title')

ChgBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (title.innerHTML === 'job') {
    title.innerHTML = 'better job'
    event.target.innerHTML = 'Change title back'
  }
  else if (title.innerHTML === 'better job') {
    title.innerHTML = 'job'
    event.target.innerHTML = 'Change Title'
  }
  else {
    console.error('Wrong')
  }
})
```