# Is it possible to extract and modify all text segments from some element ignoring all nested HTML tags? (in javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to extract and modify all text segments from some element ignoring all nested HTML tags ? (in javascript). For example:

#### INPUT

```
<body> 
 foo bar 
   <div> 
      tatatata <hr><span> ooioi</span>
   </div>
 baz 
</body>
```

#### OUTPUT

```
<body> 
 NEWfoo NEWbar 
   <div> 
      tatatata <hr><span> ooioi</span>
   </div>
 NEWbaz 
</body>
```

Comment: I just found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623180/how-can-i-replace-text-in-a-dom-element-without-replace-any-child-element Maybe here I'll find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document.body)
    .contents()   //use contents() to get the text nodes
        .each(    //Loop through all the elmenets
            function() {
                if(this.nodeType===3) { //Look for text nodes [enum is 3]
                    var txt = this.nodeValue || this.textContent;  //grab the text
                    this.nodeValue = this.textContent = "NEW" + txt + "NEW";  //set new value
                }
            }
       );
```