# Setting event.target manually

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to set event.target manually at the time of adding event handler so that `offsetX` and `offsetY` are always relative to that target.

```
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner"/>
  <div class="inner"/>
</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById("outer").addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(offsetX); // this will give offsetX relative to div.inner
                          // but i want offsetX relative to div#outer
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Because the event is on th outer div. Try with jQuery and 'next()' or 'children()' see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567709/javascript-get-child-element

Answer (score 0):

You should add a parameter to your [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). It will end up looking like this:

```
document.getElementById("outer").addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.offsetX); }
```

`ev` now captures the event, and contains certain properties that you use use. `offsetY` will also be available. If that doesn't work, you should look at [this SO post on mouse positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389156/what-substitute-should-we-use-for-layerx-layery-since-they-are-deprecated-in-web). You might be able to use `pageX` and `pageY`, or other properties that `ev` has.